# Puppet on windows: agent first run requires .NET 3.5

Tags: windows, puppet

After installing puppet onto Windows Server 2012 R2 vanilla install (nothing changed after install but some basics to work with vagrant) I install and manually run the Puppet Agent and am met with a Windows Feature pops up with an error message:

The following feature couldn't be installed: .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) ....

Any ideas? This is with Puppet 3.3.1 .... is .NET required now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Framework is not required by Puppet, but a tool that we use, elevate.exe (used only with the start menu items to ensure a privileged user in a privileged context), does require .NET Framework.

A fix that we are implementing is here: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1951

You can add this yourself as well, just add https://github.com/Iristyle/puppet-win32-ruby/blob/ticket/master/PUP-1951-override-elevate-dotnet-runtime/tools/bin/elevate.exe.config (elevate.exe.config) next to elevate so that .NET framework 4+ is counted as a supported framework. Here is that file in case the branch gets deleted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" />
      <supportedRuntime version="v3.5" />
      <supportedRuntime version="v3.0" />
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```